# Highcharts - is there a bug with stacked categories?

Tags: highcharts

I'm seeing strange behaviour in my column chart

http://jsfiddle.net/L7yd7wj5/7/

The bars are stretched over two categories and positioned incorrectly with the correct labels.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

The reason I'm using categories instead of datetime is that I wish for stacks to be shown side by side on the same date for in and out

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: "column"
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan 2 2013', 'Jan 3 2013', 'Jan 4 2013', 'Jan 5 2013', 'Jan 6 2013', 'Jan 7 2013', 'Jan 8 2013']
        },

        yAxis: {
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    if (this.total) {
                        return this.stack;
                    } else {
                         return null;   
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [
            {
                name: "Cinema",
                stack: "out",
                data: [[0,35]]
            },
            {
                name: "Sweets",
                stack: "out",
                data: [[1,12], [6,23]]
            },
            {
                name: "Games",
                stack: "out",
                data: [[4,11]]
            },
            {
                name: "Job",
                stack: "in",
                data: [[6,52]]
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: Your data set up is confusing...  You have no data points set with the same x values/stacks in order to actually stack. Is stacking what you're actually trying to achieve? Perhaps an illustration of the desired result would help

Comment: Sorry forgot to update the link, you should now see the bug I describe. I added one stacked set, I definitely require them to show total in/out on a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, `pointRange` is what you need:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    pointRange:1
  }
}
```

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/L7yd7wj5/8/

Keep in mind that since you have a grouped set up as well, there will be space for multiple bars in each category even if there is only one bar with data.

Comment: Just saved my day, thanks so much! Any idea why this did not default to 1? Was it to do with a screwy data set?

Comment: I can't specifically what the issue was, but with column series that start having problems, I always set the pointRange first, as that is often what the library has trouble interpreting when data gets more complicated